# Why the put and delete method need methodoverride?

Tags: node.js, put, http-method

What I mean is, why just let the `put` and `delete` as same as `get` and `post`,

they are all `http` method, when I want use `put` and `delete`,

I have to do some special trick, like use `methodoverride`,

Is there some technical problem about letting the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378338/what-does-connect-js-methodoverride-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

[Why don't the modern browsers support PUT and DELETE form methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177595/why-dont-the-modern-browsers-support-put-and-delete-form-methods)

to sum it up: not all browsers support sending requests other than GET and POST, nor do all server software support other verbs than GET, POST and HEAD.